# Feller semigroups and strongly continuous semigroups are the same thing?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

Revuz and Yor in their book "Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion" use the following definition of a Feller semigroup:
A Feller semigroup on $C_0(S)$ (continuous functions vanishing at infinity) is a family $T_t,\, t\geq 0$, of positive linear operators on $C_0(S)$ such that

- $T_0=Id$ and $||T_t||\leq 1$ for every $t$;
- $T_{t+s}=T_t \circ T_s$ for any pair $s, t\geq 0$;
- $\lim_{t\downarrow 0} ||T_t f - f||=0$ for every $f\in C_0(S)$

However, in more functional-analytic sources I see that if a family of bounded linear operators on some Banach space satisfies the above properties, then it is called a strongly continuous or a $C_0$ semigroup.

Questions:

- What is the actual definition of a function being strongly continuous? I cannot find it anywhere.
- Is it correct to assume that the two names are interchangeable?
- Am I right that probabilists prefer to use "Feller semigroups" because they give rise to Feller processes, while functional analysts just use the other name?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Feller semigroups are typically defined as strongly continuous semigroups with some sort of added property of how it maps nice functions to nice (potentially nicer) functions. Such as if $f \in C_0 \implies T_tf \in C_b$.

Comment: @Tom but this is not mentioned in Revuz and Yor book. It is only mentioned that a transition function is Feller if and only if (1) $P_tC_0 \subset C_0$ for each $t$ and (2) $\forall f \in C_0$, $\forall x \in S$, $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} P_t f(x) = f(x) $. But the first assertion obviously follows for the definition in the question, and so what you stated is automatically true for a Feller transtion function. Still confused :(

Comment: How does $P_tC_0 \subset C_0$ follow from the definition of a strongly continuous s.g. that you have listed above?

Comment: @Tom is it wrong because $P_t(x,E)$ is not necessarily continuous in $x$? Just to make sure I understand it correctly, the 2 assertions in my previous comment are called "Feller property", and the definition I wrote in my post is actually strong continuity. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: The symbolic phrase $\lim\limits_{t \downarrow 0} P_t f(x) = f(x)$ likely means the almost-sure or pointwise (in $x$) limit, whereas I assume $\lim\limits_{t \downarrow 0} \| P_t f - f \|$ likely means uniform limit, and the uniform limit is a stronger condition than pointwise, so under the assumption of strong continuity, the assumption (2) is free. (In fact, if memory serves, the uniform limit is why it's called "strongly" continuous semigroup rather than simply a continuous semigroup). As for Feller, property (1) is what I would consider the "Feller property" of the semigroup.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've made things clear.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hille%E2%80%93Yosida_theorem

Answer (score 4):

> What is the actual definition of a function being strongly continuous? I cannot find it anywhere.

A semigroup on $C_0(S)$ is strongly continuous iff $$\lim_{t \to 0} \|T_t f-f\| = 0 \quad \text{for all $f \in C_0(S)$}.$$

> Is it correct to assume that the two names are interchangeable?

Yes. A family of operators $(T_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is called

- a *semigroup* if $T_{t+s} = T_t \circ T_s$ and $T_0 = \text{id}$.
- *bounded* if there exists $M>0$ such that $\|T_t\| \leq M$ for all $t \geq 0$

This means that a family of operators $T_t: C_0(S) \to C_0(S)$, $t \geq 0$, is a Feller semigroup if and only if it is a bounded (with $M=1$) strongly continuous semigroup. Note that Revuz' definition contains, implicitly, that $T_t$ maps $C_0(S)$ to $C_0(S)$, i.e. $T_t f \in C_0(S)$ for any $f \in C_0(S)$; this property is called *Feller property*.

> Am I right that probabilists prefer to use "Feller semigroups" because they give rise to Feller processes, while functional analysts just use the other name?

Yes, there is a one-to-one relation between Feller semigroups and Feller processes, and therefore probabilists prefer to use this name.

Note, however, that there are different notions of "Feller semigroups" in the literature; therefore it is sometimes clearer to use the term $C_0$-semigroup to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Thank you. So a Feller semigroup is a  bounded (M=1) strongly continuous semigroup WITH the Feller property? Or not necessarily? It is not clear from your definition. Also, by saying that my definition implicitly contains the Feller property, do you mean the phrase "a family of linear operators on $C_0$"? So whe the image is not specified, it always implicitly means that the domain is mapped into itself?

Comment: @tuko A Feller semigroup has (by definition) the Feller property (and yes, I mean this phrase which you mention). [Note that this is not "my definition"... it is the one which is used in Revuz' book.]

Comment: @tuko You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that there is one difference between a Feller semigroup and a strongly continuous contraction (i.e. bounded with $M=1$) semigroup on $C_0(S)$: A Feller semigroup is always positive, i.e. every positive function is mapped to positive one, while a strong continuous contraction semigroup is not necessarily positive. To be rigorous, a Feller semigroup is a strongly continuous, positive, contraction semigroup on $C_0(S)$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. Just as a note, complementary remarks to an existing answer can be comments, to reduce clutter.